# Range related to quadratic function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given $ a , b $ and  $ x$ are three real numbers such that
$
\begin{cases}
a+b+x=2
\\
4ab+ax+bx=3
\end{cases}
$
.
Find the range of values of $ x $

I found this problem in a chapter(on quadratic equations) of a textbook so it should be something related to the discriminant $ \Delta $. I tried to form an equation with roots $a $ and $b$ and then an inequality with $k$ but ended up with a useless inequality $1 \ge 0$ .

Have I missed anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eliminate $a$ in the equations

$$a+b+x=2, \>\>\>4ab+ax+bx=3$$

to get

$$4b^2+4(x-2)b+(3-2x+x^2)=0$$

If $b$ is real, the discriminate satisfies

$$16(x-2)^2-16(3-2x+x^2)\ge 0 $$

which leads to $x\le \frac 12$.

Comment: Thank you. I was actually on the right path but I made a mistake in solving the inequality that I failed to spot even after checking twice.

Comment: @AnsonNG - Yeah, if could be tricky. I got it right after a couple of checks.